# Character formula for real representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

For an irreducible representation of a complex semisimple Lie algebra the Weyl character formula is well known. The real representations of a real semisimple Lie algebra are classified using their complexifications (see [real representation of real semi simple Lie algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151357/real-representation-of-real-semi-simple-lie-algebra)). For an irreducible real representation of a real semisimple Lie algebra is there a Weyl kind of character formula known ?